# Ninject UserManager and UserStore

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller, ninject

What is the most elegant way to inject UserManager and UserStore into a controller using ninject? For example, the context can be injected like this:

```
 kernel.Bind<EmployeeContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
    private EmployeeContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Can ninject inject UserManager and UserStore with a one line of code into a controller?! If not, what is the easiest way?
I don't want to use this:

```
 var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing, you only need to make sure there's bindings for all dependencies (`ApplicationDbContext`, `UserManager<T>` and `UserStore<T>`). Binding open generics is done like this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserStore<>)).ToSelf().InRequestScope(); // scope as necessary.
```

if it would have an interface, you'd bind it like this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<>)).To(typeof(UserStore<>));
```

So, with these bindings you should be good to go:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserManager<>)).ToSelf(); // add scoping as necessary
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserStore<>)).ToSelf(); // add scoping as necessary
```

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit...thanks. Last question...how do I inject them into controller? I can inject the context, but am not sure about Usermanager and Userstore

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to do it the exact same way as with the context? I quite positive it should work. If not please provide exact code / exception log ...

Comment: This is new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991796/how-do-i-let-ninject-inject-dependencies-into-my-mvc-controllers/23993187#23993187 I want to replace var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())); I can replace context, but don't know how to replace UserManager, UserStore

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to bind IUserStore to UserStore to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Spent 8 hours trying to figure this one out, and I think I have it.  The one difference that might need to be modified in other implementations is the SharedContext.  My code has a SharedContext that inherits from DBContext.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).To(typeof(SharedContext)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>)).To(typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>)).ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

I Also made changes to the AccountController.

```
//public AccountController()
        //    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new SharedContext())))
        //{

        //}

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore)
        {
            _userStore = userStore;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager { get; set; }
        private UserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore { get; set; }
```

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: I think this does the job well.  I will implement it when I go back to this code.