# How do I let Ninject inject dependencies into my MVC controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

How do you inject UserManager and UserStore into a controller? Ninject bindings are:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserManager<>)).ToSelf().InRequestScope(); 
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserStore<>)).ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ninject UserManager and UserStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968065/ninject-usermanager-and-userstore)

Comment: @HuorSwords this was my question. The answer is correct, but I don't know how to inject UserStore and UserManager into controller!

Comment: I think that you must retrieve the bound objects at single top-level factory (or master controller) and pass it through consumer classes (using constructor or property injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to auto-wire MVC controllers, you need to either replace MVC's default `IControllerFactory` or the default `IDependencyResolver`. There's a [Ninject.MVC3 Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3/) that implements a dependency resolver for you. You can more information about how to integrate Ninject with MVC on [this Ninject integration page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3).